# How long was Boba Fett with the Tuskens?

Tags: star-wars, the-book-of-boba-fett

Very mild spoilers follow.

- In *Return of the Jedi*, Boba Fett falls into the Sarlac pit in ABY 4, just before the rebels attack the second Death Star
- *The Mandalorian* takes places five years later in ABY 9

In *The Book of Boba Fett*, episode 4, it is established that the episode takes place after the start of The Mandalorian when Fett finds Fennec Shand wounded in the desert. But during the first three episodes, Fett didn't really do much, other than train with the Tuskens.

Did the training really take five years? Is there confirmation for this from some other source?

Comment: Aw man... that's going to mess with the timeline of things if it turns out they just made a mistake. It doesn't *seem* like there's that much time passage.

Comment: This borders on future works. We know when he first starts with the Tuskens and when he meets up with Dinn. We do not know when he left the Tuskens yet, but most likely will as more unfolds in each episode.

Comment: It's also possible that it took him a considerable amount of time to escape the Sarlacc pit. The schedule for digestion is on the order of a thousand years, so who knows?

Comment: @samuei How did he not die of thirst?

Comment: IIRC, don't we see him raiding other victims for air and such? No reason he couldn't have also been taking water and nutrition, as well. Or perhaps the armor recycles that.

Answer (score 9):

As noted in a dialog line in Episode 4, and quoted in [Why does Boba Fett look for his armor in the Sarlacc Pit?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259632/why-does-boba-fett-look-for-his-armor-in-the-sarlacc-pit?noredirect=1&lq=1), it seems it really has been years.

> "The Sarlacc Pit. That's where I was trapped all those years ago."