# Why does Boba Fett look for his armor in the Sarlacc Pit?

Tags: star-wars, boba-fett, the-book-of-boba-fett

In *The Book of Boba Fett*, Episode 4, Boba Fett

> flies to the Sarlacc Pit to look for his armor after having recovered his ship.

But why did he think it would be there? In Episode 1, we clearly see him

> climbing out of the sand with his armor on and looking up at the sky. He falls unconscious, but wakes up while the Jawas steal his armor. He is knocked out by the Jawas again, though.

The likeliest explanation is that he lost his memory of climbing out, either due to trauma / near-death experience or due to being knocked out (not really realistic but a common enough trope). But even assuming that, logically, there's no way the armor would be in there. It's even a plot point in the episode that without the armor, the acid would have dissolved him. He was wearing the armor when he fell in the pit, so the only way it would be in there was if he took it off *while in the pit* and climbed out without it. Boba should know all this, so why would he assume the armor would be in there?

Comment: Given he was quite out of it post-escape he might have mistakenly thought it was the Tuskens who stripped his armour off him before capturing him, and that as they didn’t have it, they’d abandoned it right next to the Sarlacc pit, where it had subsequently fallen back in.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Interesting idea! Though the tuskens appear to be quite keen on scrap metal based on their reactions to Boba's gift in episode 2 (or 3?) later on, so hard to image they would let beskar armor just lying around.

Comment: Sure, but he apparently [spent quite some time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259562/how-long-was-boba-fett-with-the-tuskens) with the Tuskens, and joined their tribe, so at some point he probably asked them whether they'd sold his armour.

Comment: It's not really a plot point that the armor saved him from being dissolved, just supposition from Fennec. At least in legends, I'm pretty sure it was supposed to take centuries for the sarlacc to digest someone.

Comment: @Harabeck C3PO says something along those lines in _Return of the Jedi_. Still, there's no reason for Boba to take off the armor while still inside the pit.

Comment: @MortizLost: Although, the most vulnerable part of armor doesn't tend to be the plating, but what holds it together. I could readily see the Sarlacc acid dissolving the connecting bits (here, probably more likely gaskets to seal off the wearer from gasses, vacuum, etc than bits of leather to hold the plates together), leaving the armor to slough off during the escape. Since it's the beskar that's the rare and expensive material, that's what he'd be wanting to retrieve.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots That's a good guess as to what Boba might have assumed to have happened, definitely plausible!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Boba did seem quite out of it after his escape from the Sarlacc pit; he apparently doesn't remember the Jawas taking his armour, and might have assumed the pit would scare them off.

He seems to have [spent a considerable amount of time with the Tuskens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259562/how-long-was-boba-fett-with-the-tuskens), and he became a member of their tribe, so at some point he probably asked them whether they'd been in possession of his armour, which they hadn't.

With all other possibilities eliminated, what remains — the armour falling off his prone body (or being stripped and left there by other parties) and rolling right back down into the Sarlacc — must be the truth. That process works great if you're Sherlock Holmes, less so if you're an ex-bounty-hunter from Kamino with pretty severe acid burn injuries.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like the best explanation right now. Maybe the upcoming episodes will provide an explanation.

Comment: In the [dialog for episode 4](https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=1171&t=50624), where they fly above the Scarlacc Pit Boba says _"The Sarlacc Pit. That's where I was trapped all those years ago"_ So yes, he was years with the Tuscans.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: well, technically he could have been with the Tuskens for 11 months, then rode his bantha buddy aimlessly around the desert for a few years before he rescued Fennec. But it does seem somewhat more likely he was with the Tuskens for years.

Answer (score -4):

It's a mistake by the script writers. Why?

- It can't be because he "forgot" what happened to his armor. What we see in every episode are flashbacks: they're his own memories. So he clearly remembers leaving the pit with his armor on, and being stripped of it afterwards.
- It can't have been thrown by the Jawa into the pit. They know how precious Beskar is and there's no way they would get rid of it.

The only way the writers can fix this is by giving us another flashback showing Boba trying to get his armor from the Jawa or whoever bought/acquired it from them, and somehow it ends up in the Sarlacc again (maybe along with the Jawa!).

However that's something they should have done earlier, it's out of sequence now so I doubt they'll do that in future episodes.

Comment: You could improve this answer by editing it to clarify why you're sure the flashbacks were of events that Boba Fett still remembered, as opposed to flashbacks of events he'd forgotten, shown solely for the benefit of the viewing audience.

Comment: “What we see in every episode are flashbacks: they're his own memories” — the show hasn’t told us that. The nearest we get is Boba telling Fennec after he gets out of the bacta pod that “the dreams are back”. And he was in the bacta pod for healing, so if they are memories, they might only be coming back to him thanks to the bacta pod, which he hasn’t yet started using when he looks for his armour in the Sarlacc.

Comment: "What we see in every episode are flashbacks: they're his own memories." Wrong, this is merely a nice way to introduce flashbacks during episodes. One obvious example of this is that we see a scene of the train-conductor droid after it jumped out of the window, which Boba could not have seen himself. Similarly, we see the argument in the bar with the biker gang before Boba enters it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite good points, good points!

Comment: @NicolasConnault Like mum always said, I'm full of them! Or was it "full of it", I  forget.

Answer (score -4):

Boba Fett emerging from the sands in the sarlacc's pit was a hallucination created by his mind under the influence of the mind-altering neurotoxins in the stomach of the sarlacc. Boba, probably, had to remove his armor to escape from the sarlacc stomach and the pit -Which explains the gruesome scars that Boba Fett sports on his face-, thus, his armor remains in the pit for a forthcoming retrieval in next episodes.

Comment: What if _all of Star Wars_  after _Return of the Jedi_ is just Boba's dying hallucination in the Sarlacc pit?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Nothing less than a millennium while he has been digested by the sarlacc!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 -Which Jawas? The ones with red eyes or the ones with yellow eyes?

Comment: Now, after watching the Sequel trilogy and reading this, I'm hoping that I'm inside a Sarlacc pit and hallucinating while being slowly digested. Anything has to be better than watching these movies...